# ajax autocomplete search with image result

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, theme, fatal-error

I tried to install **some extensions** regarding **Ajax search form**
I would like search in the catalog via ajax, so have suggestions and images in the results (see image)
When i Install any extensions, once back in the backend, the menu: system>>configuration don't appear, this is the error message:

> "Fatal error: Class 'Magebuzz_Searchautocomplete_Helper_Data' not
>   found in /home/catoccim/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547"

I have to uninstall the extension for continue working.
I tried different extension but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The Data.php Helper is not registered or exists, and Magento trying to load it. This is the reason why you get this error. I suggest you to check if this class exists, and the configuration for helper are properly in this module. 
To test your class if it exists after you are done with configuration in config.xml for this helper, add a test.php file in your root of website with the followinn content:

```
    <?php 

        include "app/Mage.php";
        Mage::app();
        $helper = Mage:helper("your helper configuration for this module");
        var_dump(get_class($helper));

     ?>
```

After you creted this file, open it from url (yourwebsite.com/test.php) or terminal `php test.php`

Comment: Hello, tnx for your reply

this is the message after run test.php


Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /home/catoccim/public_html/test.php on line 5

Comment: @LucaBernabei can you post all test.php file here please?